# rails_admin edit belongs_to ordering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I'm trying to override the default ordering of the belongs_to drop-downs for the new/edit forms. I'd like to order the belongs_to relationships to name instead of the default id desc.

Based on the wiki (https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Associations-scoping) I have this:

```
 field :theme do
  associated_collection_cache_all false 
    associated_collection_scope do
      Proc.new { |scope|
        scope = scope.reorder("themes.name ASC")
      }
    end
  end
 end
```

The reorder seems to be ignored while where statements are picked up.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the column you're trying to sort by is 'names' and not 'name'?

A good way to debug this would be to open a rails console and see if your reorder actually works this way.

```
Theme.all.reorder("themes.names ASC")
```

I'm guessing that probably won't work as expected and you need to tweak the reorder.

If you want to see the SQL it's creating, you can do this.

```
Theme.all.reorder("themes.names ASC").to_sql
```

That might give you more information about whats going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. You are right I meant to type name singular. Everything checks out in the console- it returns values in the proper order.

Comment: @mscccc did you find a solution ?